# error on decision trees

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have a dataset including 377 obs and 7 variables. ( I assume it is not very big data set) when I tried to generate Decision trees using Party package. I get following error:

```
   Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8 Gb
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In matrix(0, nrow = p * q, ncol = p * q) :
    Reached total allocation of 8107Mb: see help(memory.size)
    2: In matrix(0, nrow = p * q, ncol = p * q) :
    Reached total allocation of 8107Mb: see help(memory.size)
    3: In matrix(0, nrow = p * q, ncol = p * q) :
    Reached total allocation of 8107Mb: see help(memory.size)
    4: In matrix(0, nrow = p * q, ncol = p * q) :
    Reached total allocation of 8107Mb: see help(memory.size).
```

My laptop has 8gb ram and I dont get why I keep getting these error message.

Comment: Such memory problems can occur when you have categorical variables with a lot of levels where `ctree()` exhaustively has to search through all splits into two groups. Maybe you can post some more detail about the data you used (or even the entire data) along with the `ctree()` call employed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're running out of RAM. R will get the memory limit to default to what the OS says is available. I think you might be able to set the memory allocation higher and it will just use virtual memory (the disk) instead? But I'm not sure, best bet is get more RAM.

I just had this problem today on my 8GB laptop so I waited til I got home and ran it on my 32GB desktop which worked without issue.